# Populate Angularjs datatable dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using dynamic tab view using angularjs, here tabs are populated according records in database and that works fine using following code.

```
<tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" select="getContent(workspace.id)" data-id="{{workspace.id}}" heading="{{workspace.name}}" active=workspace.active>
            <div ng-init="workspace=workspace">
                <div ng-bind-html="workspace.content.outerHTML"></div>
            </div>     
        </tab>
</tabset>
```

But in my case for all tab contents I want to populate angularjs datatable.
So I add content to table using following code.

```
$scope.workspaces[i].content = $compile(angular.element('<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" datatable dt-instance="dtIntanceCallback" dt-options="dtOptionItem" dt-columns="dtColumnItem"  dt-column-defs="dtColumnItemDefs" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>'))($scope)[0];
$scope.workspaces[i].active = true;
```

And trying to apply angular datatable

```
$scope.dtIntanceCallback = function (instance) {
      $scope.dtInstanceItem = instance;
}

$scope.dtInstanceItem = {};
var defaultSorting = true;

$scope.dtOptionItem = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', function (data, callback, settings) {

 if (defaultSorting) {
     defaultSorting = false;
     var sort_order = 'DESC';
     var sort_by = 'product_id';
 } else {
     var sort_order = data.order[0].dir;
     var sort_by = data.columns[data.order[0].column].name;
 }   

 $http.post(path + "/SalesReport/getMarketPlacesItems", {
      length: data.length,
      start: data.start,
      draw: data.draw,
      column_name: sort_by,
      order: sort_order,
      search: data.search.value,
      marketplace_id: marketPlaceId
 }).then(function (res) {
      try {
          var obj = JSON.parse(response.data);
          if (obj.status == "101") {
              restSessionOut.getRstOut();
          }
      } catch (err) {
      }
      if (res.data){
          callback({
                    draw: res.data.draw,
                    recordsTotal: res.data.recordsTotal,
                    recordsFiltered: res.data.recordsFiltered,
                    data: res.data.market_place_data
                    });
      }
 });
 })
   .withDataProp('data')
   .withOption('processing', true)
   .withOption('serverSide', true)
   .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
   .withOption('destroy', true)
   .withDisplayLength(10)
   .withBootstrap()
   .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

$scope.dtColumnItem = [

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('productImage').withTitle("Product Picture").withOption('sName', 'productImage').renderWith(renderProductImage),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('asin1').withTitle("ASIN").withOption('sName', 'asin1'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('title').withTitle("Product Name").withOption('sName', 'title'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('seller_sku').withTitle("SKU").withOption('sName', 'seller_sku'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('today_sales').withTitle("Sales Today").withOption('sName', 'today_sales'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('today_sales_net').withTitle("Net Sales Today").withOption('sName', 'today_sales_net'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('today_unit_price').withTitle("Today's Unit Price").withOption('sName', 'today_unit_price'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('yes_sales').withTitle("Yesterday Today").withOption('sName', 'yes_sales'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('yes_sales_net').withTitle("Net Sales Yesterday").withOption('sName', 'yes_sales_net'),

DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('yes_unit_price').withTitle("Yesterday's Unit Price").withOption('sName', 'yes_unit_price'),
];

$scope.dtColumnItemDefs = [
       DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()
];


function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
         $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
}

function renderProductImage(data, type, full, meta){
         return '<img src="asin_img/'+data+'" height="60" width="60">';                            
}
```

Searching-pagination is not displayed and sorting is not working.

Comment: what is the line number for that error? (I can't find any occurence of 'aDataSort')

Comment: Yes, There is no occurrence of aDataSort in this code.

Comment: "*Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined*" appears then there is a mismatch between header definitions and columns. But your code contain so much "crreative coding" and misunderstandings that a simple answer is not possible. We can start with your double use of instances, and that you declare anything in a instance callback that is probably never executed, or at least executed long after the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad, I fixed the error "Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined", and data is displayed in my table. but now searching and pagination is not showing and sorting is now working. There is not error now.

Comment: I edited the code, with working code.